# How to use "sigaltstack" in signal handler program?

Tags: c, posix, signals

Do anyone know how to use the [sigaltstack](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaltstack.html) in a real signal handler program? A simple but complete code may be great help!

Comment: // , This could probably use some formatting improvement. Have you tried anything so far? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a minimal sample program that uses `sigaltstack` to catch infinite recursion. If you comment out the `sigaltstack` call or `SA_ONSTACK` flag, the signal handler will not be able to run because it has no stack left and the program will just crash.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void handler(int sig)
{
    write(2, "stack overflow\n", 15);
    _exit(1);
}
unsigned infinite_recursion(unsigned x) {
    return infinite_recursion(x)+1;
}
int main()
{
    static char stack[SIGSTKSZ];
    stack_t ss = {
        .ss_size = SIGSTKSZ,
        .ss_sp = stack,
    };
    struct sigaction sa = {
        .sa_handler = handler,
        .sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK
    };
    sigaltstack(&ss, 0);
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, 0);
    infinite_recursion(0);
}
```

A more sophisticated use might actually perform `siglongjmp` to jump out of the signal handler and back to a point where the infinite recursion can be avoided. This is not valid if async-signal-unsafe library calls are being used, or if your data might be left in an unsafe/unrecoverable state, but if you're performing pure arithmetic computations, it may be valid.

Perhaps a better task for the signal handler would be performing an emergency dump of any valuable/critical data that wasn't already saved to disk. This could be difficult if you can't call async-signal-unsafe functions, but it's usually possible if you put some effort into it.

Comment: It works fine for me (after fixing the one typo). Incidentally, with optimization enabled, gcc generates an infinite loop rather than recursion for the function and thus never overflows the stack. With `-O0`, the signal handler runs as expected.

Comment: I tried with -O0 as you said but it still gives me a sementation fault. Can it be the gcc version?

Comment: Perhaps try running it in gdb and see where it stops. You'll have to `continue` the first time it hits `SIGSEGV` to let the signal handler run.

Comment: On some systems, stack overflow might give `SIGSTKFLT` rather than `SIGSEGV`, so you might need to handle both to be "portable".

Comment: @Hola Soy Edu, Have you set `ss` with a *designated initializer list* as @R.. did? If not, the problem might be in `ss.ss_flags`. It must be *zero* to [establish a new alternate signal stack](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaltstack). I'll suggest an edit to emphasize that.

Comment: @Mawg: Looks like it. That was a long time ago, though,

Answer (score 1):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void handler(int signo)
{
    int x;
    if(signo == SIGSEGV)
    {
        printf("Waoh, caught signal %s\n",strsignal(signo));
        printf("Top of stack is near %10p", (void*)&x);
    }
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void overflowStack(int i)
{
    char a[8964];
    printf("(%d) Called overflow function. The top of stack is near %10p\n",i ,&a[0]);
    overflowStack(i+1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    /*(1)specify that the signal handler will be allocated onto the
    alternate signal stack*/
    stack_t sigstack;
    //malloc return the pointer to the allocated memory on success
    //malloc return NULL on error
    sigstack.ss_sp = malloc(SIGSTKSZ);
    if( sigstack.ss_sp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Err: malloc error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sigstack.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
    sigstack.ss_flags = 0;

    /*(2)Specify that the signal handler will be allocated on the alternate 
    signal stack */
    if(sigaltstack(&sigstack, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("Err: sigaltstack error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // sbrk() change the location of the program break, which defines the end of the process's data segment 
    //On success, sbrk() returns the previous program break. 
    printf("Now the alternate signal stack is successfully allocated\n");
    printf("The address of signal stack is : %10p - %10p\n",sigstack.ss_sp,(char*)sbrk(0)-1);

    /*(3)define a struct sigaction to deal with the SIGSEGV*/
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL);

    overflowStack(1);

}
```

Comment: Output:           Now the alternate signal stack is successfully allocated
The address of signal stack is : 0x563078b3c260 - 0x563078b5cfff
(1) Called overflow function. The top of stack is near 0x7ffdad9eed00
(2) Called overflow function. The top of stack is near 0x7ffdad9ec9d0
(3) Called overflow function. The top of stack is near 0x7ffdad9ea6a0
(929) Called overflow function. The top of stack is near 0x7ffdad1f5f00
Waoh, caught signal Segmentation fault