# How to handle this exception? (zero esp)

Tags: c++, assembly

How to handle this exception?

```
__asm
{
  mov esp, 0
  mov eax, 0
  div eax
}
```

This is not handled with `try/except` or `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()`.

Comment: It is over, you can't execute any code with a non-functional stack.

Comment: on UNIX, it's at least possible to detect / intercept this. You can request signal handlers to run on dedicated stacks, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785746/how-to-use-sigaltstack-in-signal-handler-program for details. The question with all such things is, like "what _exactly_ do you _mean_ when you say 'handle' this ?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is running in an operating system, the operating system will catch the divide by zero, and then ATTEMPT to form an exception/signal stackframe for the application code. However, since the user-mode stack is "bad", it can't.

There is really no way for the operating system to deal with this, other than kill the application. [Theoretically, the could make up a new stack from some dynamically allocated memory, but it's pretty pointless, as there is no (always working) way for the application itself to recover to a sane state].

Don't set the stack pointer to something that isn't the stack - or if you do store "random" data in the stack pointer register, do not have exceptions. It's the same as "don't aim a gun at your foot and pull the trigger, unless you want to be without your foot".

Edit:

If the code is running in "kernel mode" rather than "usermode", it's even more "game over", since it will "double-fault" - the processor hits a divide by zero exception handler, which tries to write to the stack, and when it does so, it faults. This is now a "fault within a fault handler", aka a "double-fault". The typical setup of the double-fault handler is to have a separate stack, which then recovers the fault handler. But it's still game over - we don't know how to return to the original fault handler [or how to find out what the original fault handler was].

If there is no "new stack" with the double fault handler, it will triple fault a x86 processor - typically, a triple fault will make the processor restart [technically, it halts the processor with a special combination of bits signalled on the address bus to indicate that it's a "triple fault". The typical PC northbridge then resets the processor in recognition that the triple fault is an unrecoverable situation - this is why sometimes your PC simply reboots when you have poor quality drivers].

Comment: In UNIX, it _is_ possible for a userland application to catch this. Not via C/C++ "builtin facilities" (so `try`/`catch` and the like, no go, OS/Hardware "exceptions" are _not the same_ as exceptions on the C++ language level), but via `sigaltstack()`. This allows the application to tell the OS "if a signal occurs, run the signal handler on this other stack". See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaltstack.html

Comment: It is however extremely unlikely that you can continue at that point. It may be possible to, for example, `longjump()` back to some point where the code has previously been, but it's almost certainly "you have to stop now...)

Comment: I've not said you can meaningfully _recover_ (there's only a few HW-exception type situations where you can ...) - but you can intercept and "die with grace". From reading the Windows docs, I'd think that in Windows, you could achieve a similar thing to `sigaltstack` using a trick: spawn a separate thread (which then has its own separate stack) whose only job/task it is to become _a debugger to its own process_. Let that handle what windows calls the _last-chance notification_, and voila, you can now detect stackpointer corruption in other threads of the process ?

Comment: Yes, ok, I admit that there are ways to achieve that. Nothing particularly portable, and nothing that achieves much more than "Sorry, I'm now dead because some idiot managed to set the stack to zero".

Comment: @MatsPetersson that little piece of message is precisely the thing which saves you days wasted on "root cause analysis"; if the business-critical app goes down without logs/traces/a dump, someone somewhere usually presses the question "do we need to replace the 200000$ hardware ?" to those responsible for provisioning. And yes, there is business-critical code written by, for lack of a less-profane word, "real code monkeys" (no offense please; noone ever considers all issues and what's obvious how-to-do to one isn't to another). "Graceful death" saves money ;-)

Comment: Yeah, you still need to be able to find the original stack frame and dump that to be able to make some sort of "sense" out of it. If you are REALLY lucky, you have code like the above, where the code is absolutely crooked, but every time I've seen zero in the stackpointer, it's because someone has stored a bunch of zeros past the end of an array, and when the code comes to return from the stack, it restores frame pointer from the stack, and then when you get back from that, stack pointer from frame pointer - so now you need to know where the stack was...

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to try to interact with a higher-level language's exception mechanism from embedded assembly. The compiler can do "magic" that you cannot match, and there's no (portable) way to tell the compiler that "this assembly code might throw an exception".

Comment: What should I do for handle this exception?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that there is NOTHING you can do. What are you ACTUALLY trying to solve (this has a feeling of XY question).

Comment: I'm writing a simple program for emulate malware and want for handle exception with cpu ,,, with this problem i hande exception without cpu

Comment: Well, the problem here is that you need to emulate what the processor does in the kernel. Aside from details such as "how the processor and exception handler is actually configured at the time", this is covered by Intel's and AMD's documentation for their respective processors (the handling is the same on both types - use whichever you prefer).