# How can I allocate more stack in my program's death throes?

Tags: c, stack-overflow

On a Posix system, I am coding a signal handler, using [sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

I would like to record some debug information, before calling `exit()`. This involves a few procedure calls.

If we have had a stack overflow, is there any way that I can make those function calls without messing things up further?

I know that after I do my debug stuff, I am going to call `exit()`, so we won't ever unwind the stack. Could I code a small assembler insert to set the stack pointer to the base of the stack?

Never mind that I am trashing it; it won't be needed later, and by trashing the start of the stack, I am not trashing beyond the end of it.

Has anyone done this, or an alternative, and shown it to work?

Comment: If you want to do this inside of a signal-handler, why don't you just set up a `sigaltstack`, so the limit on the main stack doesn't matter?

Comment: Becuase I was unawre of it (sheepish grinn).  Feel free to post this as an answer. Detail would be nice, but I can Google for it, now that you have given me a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On POSIX, you can set up a separate stack for specific signal-handlers with `sigaltstack()`. The manpage on Linux for this function is very nice:

> The most common usage of an alternate signal stack is to handle the
>   SIGSEGV
>          signal that is generated if the space  available  for  the  normal  process
>          stack  is  exhausted:  in this case, a signal handler for SIGSEGV cannot be
>          invoked on the process stack; if we wish to  handle  it,  we  must  use  an
>          alternate signal stack.

One thing to keep in mind is that you need to use `sigaction()` rather than `signal()` to establish the relevant signal-handler, but that's a good idea anyway. Also, the `sa_flags` for `sigaction()`s `struct sigaction` need to contain `SA_ONSTACK`.

Comment: Sounds goo! This related question gives a code example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785746/how-to-use-sigaltstack-in-signal-handler-program

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that your program use *the stack* (for callframes, as opposed to the data structure). Being a turing-complete programming language, you can rewrite any *functionally recursive loop* (e.g. loops using function invocation) as a *procedurally recursive loop* (e.g. procedural loops such as `for`, `while` and `do .. while`) providing you introduce the appropriate language and data structures.

You might then find growing a *stack* (data structure, not the same as the callframe) to several gigabytes is trivial for most laptops using `realloc`... As an added bonus, you'll no longer need to delve into non-portable hacks such as implementation-defined assembler notations or signals.