How do I catch SIGSEGV with sigaction() when using JNI?
I've found a bug, but I'm not sure whether to blame the JVM, JNI, NASM, GCC, or ld.
After several days of carefully shaving my original program down, I've finally got a minimal reproducible example which shows that errors like FATAL ERROR in native method: Static field ID passed to JNI have a roughly 1 in 20 chance of being printed when these conditions are met:

JNI is used to call a C function that opens mage.so
mage.so was generated with ld from mage.o, where mage.o was generated with nasm from mage.s (where mage.s can just be an empty file)
After loading mage.so, JNI is used to call a C function that causes a SIGSEGV

I have been able to reproduce the errors on both my Ubuntu and Arch Linux computers.
What's strange is that generating mage.o from an empty mage.c with gcc, instead of using NASM, does not cause the errors to be printed, which is why I think NASM may be to blame. But regardless of whether the bug is caused by NASM or not, the title of this question is still my ultimate goal here.
Context
My goal is to catch SIGSEGVs from native code, since I want to prevent Minecraft (Java) from crashing whenever a mod written in my compiled modding language contains accidental infinite recursion.
Since my modding language generates the bytes in the .so files all by itself, I diff the bytes against the ones NASM generates in my tests to ensure correctness. Mimicking NASM's output bytes is much simpler than mimicking GCC's, since GCC outputs way more bloat.
I've been able to successfully use my modding language in other programs (written in C/C++/Python) using sigaction() and sigsetjmp(), but it isn't as easy in Java, as described by this Stack Overflow answer:

The Java VM (at least Oracles implementation, which also includes the OpenJDK) uses POSIX signals for internal communication, so it installs signal handlers e.g. for SIGSEGV. That means, to work correctly, the Java VM must get and examine any SIGSEGV which happens in the process, to distinguish between "communication" SIGSEGVs and real ones which would be program errors.
But signal handlers are a global resource, within a process any native code can install signal handlers and replace the ones the Java VM installed.
To solve this problem (user-installed signal handlers replace the JavaVM signal handlers) and to accomodate user code which may have a reason to install signal handlers, Java VM uses "signal chainging", which basically means that the signal handlers (VM and Users) are chained behind each other: the JavaVM signal handlers run first; if they think the signal is of no interest to the VM, it hands down the signal to the user handler.
The libjsig.so is the answer for this problem: it replaces the system signal APIs (sigaction() etc) with its own versions, and any user code attempting to install a signal handler will not replace the global signal handler but the user handler will be chained behind the (already installed) Java VM signal handler.

It's incredibly easy to accidentally have undefined behavior when siglongjmp()ing out of a signal handler, as described in the APPLICATION USAGE section of this page, which is why my modding language blocks (using sigprocmask) and disables the signal handler at strategic moments.
Minimal reproducible example
Main.java:
class Main {
    private native void init();
    private native void foo();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.loadLibrary("foo");

        init();

        long iteration = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Iteration: " + ++iteration);
            foo();
        }
    }
}

foo.c:
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

jmp_buf jmp_buffer;

// Accessing this from a handler is possibly undefined behavior,
// but removing this does not impact the overall results anyways
volatile pthread_t expected_thread;

static void segv_handler(int sig) {
    (void)sig;

    char msg[] = "In segv_handler()\n";
    write(STDERR_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);

    if (!pthread_equal(pthread_self(), expected_thread)) {
        char msg2[] = "Unexpected thread entered handler; exiting\n";
        write(STDERR_FILENO, msg2, sizeof(msg2)-1);
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    siglongjmp(jmp_buffer, 1);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    (void)env;
    (void)obj;

    fprintf(stderr, "Initializing...\n");

    struct sigaction sigsegv_sa = {
        .sa_handler = segv_handler,
        .sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK, // SA_ONSTACK gives SIGSEGV its own stack
    };

    // Handle stack overflow
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7342398/13279557
    static char stack[SIGSTKSZ];
    stack_t ss = {
        .ss_size = SIGSTKSZ,
        .ss_sp = stack,
    };

    if (sigaltstack(&ss, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaltstack");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (sigfillset(&sigsegv_sa.sa_mask) == -1) {
        perror("sigfillset");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sigsegv_sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    void *dll = dlopen("./mage.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!dll) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dlopen(): %s\n", dlerror());
    }
}

void recurse() {
    recurse();
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_foo(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    (void)env;
    (void)obj;

    expected_thread = pthread_self();

    if (sigsetjmp(jmp_buffer, 1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Jumped\n");
        return;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Recursing...\n");

    recurse();
}

mage.s: an empty file
mage.c: an empty file
Compiling foo.so (you will need to replace the jdk include paths here with your own, which ls /usr/lib/jvm can help with):
gcc foo.c -o libfoo.so -shared -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -Wfatal-errors -Wno-infinite-recursion -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-23.0.1-oracle-x64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-23.0.1-oracle-x64/include/linux

Then assemble mage.s to mage.o:
nasm mage.s -felf64

And link mage.o to mage.so:
ld mage.o -o mage.so -shared

Followed by running this a couple dozen times, until you see FATAL ERROR in native method: Static field ID passed to JNI being printed:
java -Xcheck:jni -Djava.library.path=. Main.java

You can use this in a second terminal to kill the program when it hangs:
pkill -9 -f 'java -Xcheck:jni -Djava.library.path=. Main.java'

For some reason generating mage.o from compiling mage.c, instead of from assembling mage.s, never prints the error:
gcc mage.c -c

What I also don't understand is why the pthread_equal() check I put in the signal handler does not prevent the FATAL ERROR in native method: Static field ID passed to JNI from being printed. I figured that the error was caused by an internal JVM thread entering my handler, instead of JVM's own SIGSEGV handler, but I guess not?
Using jsig
Running Main.java, with libjsig.so:
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-23.0.1-oracle-x64/lib/server/libjsig.so java -Xcheck:jni -Djava.library.path=. Main.java

prints this:
Initializing...
Iteration: 1
Recursing...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Note how "In segv_handler()" was not printed.
As aled commented, what's happening here is that using jsig guarantees that the JVM receives the SIGSEGV before my custom handler does. Since the JVM considers it unrecoverable, and apparently doesn't want to pass the responsibility of handling the SIGSEGV to my own handler, it does not call it, resulting in the crash.
If I leave the LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-23.0.1-oracle-x64/lib/server/libjsig.so out when running Main.java, it complains that it wants me to use jsig, which is expected:
Warning: SIGSEGV handler modified!
Signal Handlers:
   SIGSEGV: segv_handler in libfoo.so, mask=11111111011111111101111111111110, flags=SA_ONSTACK, unblocked
  *** Handler was modified!
  *** Expected: javaSignalHandler in libjvm.so, mask=11100100110111111111111111111110, flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
    SIGBUS: javaSignalHandler in libjvm.so, mask=11100100010111111101111111111110, flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, unblocked
    SIGFPE: javaSignalHandler in libjvm.so, mask=11100100010111111101111111111110, flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, unblocked
   SIGPIPE: javaSignalHandler in libjvm.so, mask=11100100010111111101111111111110, flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, unblocked
   SIGXFSZ: javaSignalHandler in libjvm.so, mask=11100100010111111101111111111110, flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, unblocked
    SIGILL: javaSignalHandler in libjvm.so, mask=11100100010111111101111111111110, flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, unblocked
   SIGUSR2: SR_handler in libjvm.so, mask=00000000000000000000000000000000, flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, unblocked
    SIGHUP: UserHandler in libjvm.so, mask=11100100010111111101111111111110, flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, unblocked
    SIGINT: UserHandler in libjvm.so, mask=11100100010111111101111111111110, flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, unblocked
   SIGTERM: UserHandler in libjvm.so, mask=11100100010111111101111111111110, flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, unblocked
   SIGQUIT: UserHandler in libjvm.so, mask=11100100010111111101111111111110, flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, blocked
   SIGTRAP: SIG_DFL, mask=00000000000000000000000000000000, flags=none, unblocked
Consider using jsig library.

We've seen that leaving it out does run the for-loop, but it of course stomps on JVM's own SIGSEGV handler, though, so it's no good for continuing execution.
I found this Stack Overflow answer which explains that the JVM always terminates with a SIGABRT when a SIGSEGV is raised (assuming jsig is not used, and we've installed our own SIGSEGV handler). This allows them to run their own cleanup code before exiting, but it doesn't help me continue execution, since the handler will return to the JVM spot that raised the abort.
I'm on Ubuntu 24.04.1, and here's more version info:
$ java --version
java 23.0.1 2024-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 23.0.1+11-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0.1+11-39, mixed mode, sharing)

$ nasm --version
NASM version 2.16.01 # 2.16.03-1 also reproduces the error

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 13.3.0-6ubuntu2~24.04) 13.3.0

$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42


" the signal handlers (VM and Users) are chained behind each other: the JavaVM signal handlers run first; if they think the signal is of no interest to the VM, it hands down the signal to the user handler." If I'm reading this correctly the JVM considers SIGSEV interesting so it catches it first.

@aled Indeed, using jsig essentially gives the JVM the ability to handle the SIGSEGV before I do. But if I don't use jsig, I get warnings and other issues. I guess an alternative title could've been "How do I catch a native SIGSEGV with sigaction() when using JNI?"
